# Find function is missing, but not sure what to put in

Tags: cakephp

Ok, I'm trying to File & Folder classes as specified here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html#

My Folder Controller looks like this:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('Folder', 'Utility');
App::uses('File', 'Utility');

class FolderController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array();

    public function display() {

      $dir = '/var/www/html/letters/pdfdir/';
      $files = $dir->find('.*\.pdf', true);

      foreach ($files as $file) {
        $file = new File($dir->pwd() . DS . $file);
        $contents = $file->read();

        echo 'CONTENT: '.$contents;

        // $file->write('I am overwriting the contents of this file');
        // $file->append('I am adding to the bottom of this file.');
        // $file->delete(); // I am deleting this file
        $file->close(); // Be sure to close the file when you're done
      }

    }

}
```

but I get the following error:

Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object 
File: /var/www/html/letters/app/Controller/FolderController.php 
Line: 13

Any help appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake

```
$dir = '/var/www/html/letters/pdfdir/';
```

should be

```
 $dir = new Folder('/var/www/html/letters/pdfdir');
```

In your original code `$dir` is just a variable of string type. However, it should be an object of Folder class.

**Another note:** you have to remove the trailing slash.

Comment: I've manually created the folder, I don't want to create a new one. That's why I've changed that line.

Comment: Thanks, I just realised that. Changing code now to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

$dir is still a string, you need to pass it to a File or Folder object to become usable as an object.